# Unable to save connector configuration. Please try again

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I'v been trying to create a connector in MS teams but I get this error: when I click save : "Unable to save "Top.legal" connector configuration. Please try again."
I did some reseach for the problem but all of them didn't match with my case
here is my manifest.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.9",
  "id": "xxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "com.Top.legal",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.exemple.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.exemple.com/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.exemple.com/"
  },
  "description": {
    "full": "send adaptive cards",
    "short": "top legal"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline_icon.png",
    "color": "color_icon.png"
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "8e33a624-cf51-4e6d-87ec-b7eaecd98a80",
      "scopes": ["team"],
      "configurationUrl": "https://84127fa549f0.ngrok.io/connect"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "full": "Top.legal",
    "short": "Top.legal"
  },
  "permissions": ["identity", "messageTeamMembers"],
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "validDomains": ["5b6a00e5f53f.ngrok.io"]
}
```

and you can find here my config.html file  =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script src='https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js'</script</head><body>Copy your webhook URL from here to POST messages in this channel: <span id="url"></span><br><br>Don't forget to click on "Save" to activate your connector.<script>microsoftTeams.initialize();
        
        microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(s => {
            document.getElementById("url").innerText = s.webhookUrl;
            console.log(s);
             });

        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            entityId: "sampleConn",
            configName: "sampleConfig",
            contentUrl: "https://84127fa549f0.ngrok.io/connect"
        });

        

        microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);

        microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
           
            
                    saveEvent.notifySuccess();
                  
        });
    </script></body></html>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: I am able to repro the issue and taking this for internal discussion with team.

Comment: Now I am unable to repro the issue please follow [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/connector-generic/nodejs) sample code and let me know if you still persists the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add ngrok url in valid domains while registering connector in [Connectors Developer Dashboard](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/home/login/#/publish). Please follow this [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/connector-generic/nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

connect page doesn't support wildcards, kudos to Sridevi-msft

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).